# Set the cursor, bypassing cursor magnification

Tags: macos, cocoa

I'd like to set the cursor in a Mac application for a specific view without that cursor being subject to the Cursor Magnification setting in Universal Access.

As an example, I'd like to set the cursor to a preview of the brush the user has selected. It should be the size of the brush, so that the user knows what how big their brush-stroke will be. Cursor magnification throws this off; I might as well just have the arrow cursor at that point.

I *do not* want to change (and have to restore) the cursor magnification setting itself. I want specific custom cursors to not be subject to it.

Hiding the cursor and drawing a fake cursor within my view doesn't work, since it'll be clipped at the view/window edges.

I'd prefer a solution that lets me use NSCursor, but seeing no obvious solution in that class, I'd be willing to accept another solution that uses something lower-level.

Answer (score 1):

> Hiding the cursor and drawing a fake cursor within my view doesn't work, since it'll be clipped at the view/window edges.

Then an overlay window is your next best bet, I think.

Comment: The disadvantage of this is that programs that capture the cursor, such as Layers, won't capture it correctly from the overlay window. But I'll keep it in mind.